# How can quit screen without confirmation?

Tags: screen

When creating a shortcut in my .screenrc defined by

```
bindkey "^y" quit
```

I recieve the message

```
Really quit and kill all your windows [y/n]
```

How can I quit screen with my shortcut without this confirmation?